# Capacitor discharge: Is gate voltage on IGBT proportional to collector?

Tags: capacitor, igbt

I'm designing a capacitive discharge circuit. I'd like to get some feedback before I buy parts for testing. The output should be around 100v and thought an IGBT would work great in discharging the capacitor. But I'm unsure. What I'm hoping to do is switch the 100v on with a low voltage to the gate from the optocoupler. How much voltage would I need to the gate? I have a couple of question marks on my design below indicating problem areas that I'm unsure about. Please advise.

I'm open to suggestions and criticism.
[image: revision 6 of cd circuit]

Comment: I am not sure the discharge BJT will work at all. It seems your step-up transformer is insulated, so there is no clue whether the power +12V is actually at a higher voltage than HV RTN. I can't help with the IGBT though.

Comment: Moreover that TIP47 is voiding the insulation. You should use a relais or another optocoupler.

Comment: What will (or should) the voltage on the IGBT gate be when the PC713 is *not* conducting?

Comment: Voltage at gate should be zero when PC173 is not conducting.

Comment: Then make it zero! As it is now it is floating, so the IGBT could start conducting at every full moon (or any other inconvenient moment).

Comment: Can you tell us the load?  How much current are you switching? how fast?  I never used an IGBT, can you say why you pikced that rather than a mosfet... The IRF740 is good to 400V Vds  (Oh I looked up the tip47... good to 250V.)

Comment: I could use a mosfet as well. I've also thought about an SCR. In the discharge circuit I show the TIP47 transistor but am unsure as I think the base and collector voltages have to be identical. I would need a pretty hefty resistor to the base, but again may have made an error somewhere or maybe design is no good.

Comment: Re: the base resistor.  That's not too hard to pick.  You need a base current of maybe 1/10, 1/20 of the collector current.  Ic =100V/10k = 10mA, let's say Ib ~1ma, it's powered from the 12V (?) so ~ 12k, maybe 20k ohm.  As Spehro said, don't forget some resistance between 100V supply and the 1800 uF cap.

Comment: @George Actually I was thinking Ib was more like .01mA. I have three 33k resistors at the collector. Shouldn't Ic=100V/99k? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @JohnnyHolguin In your schematic you've got the three 33k's in parallel, that gives you ~10k (11k if you want to be picky), but if your intent was to put them in series, then sure scale everything by a factor of 10.  200k ohm will be fine.  (looking at the tip47 spec sheet, it doesn't give a the current gain for Ic below 10mA.. and it is showing a bit of a downward trend... but still a current gain of 10 is a good guess.)  You can always make it smaller.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Dude you're right. I was doing a series calculation. Updating schematic in a few.

Answer (score 1):

For the IGBT driver, I suggest an isolated supply (galvanically isolated DC-DC converter) and opto-gate driver. One of the easiest ways to drive the gate is with an isolated gate driver such as the Avago [ACPL-312U-000E](http://www.avagotech.com/docs/AV02-1843EN).

You need to bring the IGBT gate positive by something like 15V relative to the emitter to fully turn it on, and to drive it to zero (or a few volts negative) to fully turn it off. That should be done fast if you want the transistor to turn on snappily. It should never exceed something like +/-20V *relative to the source*. What you have there will not achieve that as the 15V from your voltage divider is relative to your load - terminal and not the IGBT source, so the gate will likely be damaged.

It's possible a variation of your circuit with the HV section flipped (load on the IGBT collector to +100V) could be made to work.. but the IGBT gate has no path to discharge the charge so it will leak off slowly, which might be disastrous.

If this is a welder you're making, keep in mind the load will short the 100V supply (the 1N4005 won't help) when the IGBT is on.

Edit: you can derive an appropriate supply voltage from the 100V for the IGBT driver as follows:

It supply between 0mA and 5mA without allowing the gate voltage to exceed the absolute maximum 20V voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH3EeH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @Stephro The dc-dc is isolated. See <a href="http://www.emcohighvoltage.com/pdfs/aseries.pdf" title="A01 Datasheet">datasheet</a>. The use of the IGBT gate driver is probably the way to go. I think I understand the IGBT a bit better now. Putting the load on the collector makes sense. But you say the gate no path to discharge? Darn these switches aren't perfect. How can I fix this? Drop down resistor to ground?

Comment: The resistor would work, but it would be slow. The gate drivers have push-pull outputs so they'll pull the gate charge out quickly.

Comment: Updated schematic to include the IGBT Gate Driver. Any feedback would be helpful.

Comment: Vcc needs a source of about 15V @ 5mA -10mA relative to emitter. Vee should connect to the emitter. Voltage divider won't give you enough current, and it's connected wrong.

Comment: Spehro I looked at data sheet and see that Vee should connect to emitter. But can you elaborate on connected wrong? Your guidance would be helpful...

Comment: Vee and Vcc are shorted . If the voltage divider (500K/110K junction) was connected to Vcc it would be correct (but you need much more current than it can deliver, by maybe 100:1) to power that isolator.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with that TIP47- it will always be on- and the gate voltage will be too high. Originally you had a switch for the TIP. Please see my edit above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15863/discussion-between-johnny-holguin-and-spehro-pefhany).